# Should this tag be removed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Just seen someone has created this silly tag: [vw-vh-vmin-vmax](/questions/tagged/vw-vh-vmin-vmax)

Should it/can it be removed?

Comment: ridiculous tags for the win!

Comment: Viewport units?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just edited the [only question with this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658635/relative-padding-and-vh-units-bug-or-spec-misunderstanding) to remove the tag.

The tag will be removed by the daily maintenance run.